# CSS form:valid selector doesn't work in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

This css doesn't work in internet explorer 11:

```
form:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/jsf2rLck/2/)

As you can see the forms are still gray in internet explorer 11 while they should be red and blue. Is there any way to fix this without using javascript?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avalid) doesn't mention any problems with it in IE11.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. It's little consolation, but there's an [issue](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/2384) on the caniuse repo to at least get this added to the :valid page. Worth mentioning that the MDN page does now make note of this.

Answer (score 0):

as might you maybe saw or probably not they even show in MDN link 
that they show input:invalid also not working only on form in ie

```
input:valid {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}
```

EXAMPLE [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tmsmncvw/)

With adding those lines with `input:valid / :invalid` it works with same behaviour

Comment: This only styles the inputs and not the entire form. With form:valid and form:invalid selectors you can for example disable submit button when any field is invalid.

Comment: you're right so it looks like or eighter it is bugged or we are missing something