# How to avoid IE11 "slow" evaluation of CSS :invalid and :valid pseudo selectors

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I'm aware of this question that shows :valid and :invalid pseudo selectors not working at all in IE11:

[CSS form:valid selector doesn't work in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556276/css-formvalid-selector-doesnt-work-in-ie11)

Yet there is also this example of floating labels:

https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/floated-label-pattern-css

Here, IE11 is behaving differently. At first, it does not seem to work. You type in the fields of the form and the CSS that is supposed to apply, doesn't, which is different from Chrome and Firefox.

However, when you exit the field, or move to the next field, you do see the CSS applied, even in IE11. As if it is "one behind".

I'm facing this exact same issue in my own implementation, which is not public. Is there a solution (non-JS) to work around this strange evaluation behavior of IE11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and since they fixed it in Edge they not likely will in IE11.

I did note one thing, CSS changes works on the input itself though, so what if you do something like this?

```css
.field, .field label {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 10px;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px 2px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

form:valid,
input:valid {
  top: 18px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" pattern=".+" required="" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for extending on your comment. A quick test shows this to be working in IE11, will further test this in my own implementation when I'm back at work (in a few days) and then mark your answer as accepted.